# how to get google search results including keyword in url?

Tags: php, search

Hello I need to check all websites contains "tomer" word in url. I need this for some copyright issues about my company.

For example when I search in google "tomer" , it should give me only "tomercompany.com", "anothertomercompany.com" etc.  How can I do that? Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **:inurl** operator

> If you include inurl: in your query, Google will restrict the results
>   to documents containing that word in the URL

[https://www.google.no/#q=inurl:tomer](https://www.google.no/#q=inurl%3atomer)